# SearchRequest does not support radius and GeoBoundingBox parameters?

Tags: android, here-api

ExploreRequest supports both  Radius and GeoBoundingBox options for search. Is there a way to use the same options for SearchRequest? I basically need to search using a query string filtered with the options mentioned. 
The REST API equivalent appears to support these options.

Answer (score 1):

No, SearchRequest doesn't have radius and bounding box.

But you should anyway also set "setMapViewport" to get the most relevant results for you.

But of course that doesn't mean the results are restricted to that area, since it's a free text search, this is intended. e.g if you search for "SF Airport", you want the right result for the San Francisco Airport, regardless your position or viewport.

If you want only results for your radius/viewport, you have to filter them afterwards by distance.